# Method to edit html/css code that contains php files?

Tags: php, mamp

I am currently making a website using html, css, php, and javascript.

The directory looks like this:

```
css
 ├─ normalize.css
 └─ styles.css
js
 └─ main.js
includes
 ├─ head.inc.php
 ├─ header.inc.php
 ├─ navbar.inc.php
 └─ footer.inc.php
assets
 └─ pictures
index.php
page1.php
page2.php
page3.php
```

I recently got the includes to work so a normal page on my website looks something like this:

**Page1.php**

```
<?
include"includes/head.inc.php"
?>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php
include "includes/header.inc.php";
?>
<?php
include "includes/navbar.inc.php";
?>
<div class= "content">
<p> Content stuff </p>
</div>
<?php
include "includes/footer.inc.php";
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To test the website currently I am using MAMP.

> I found that now the only way to make edits to the look of the website (not the content) was to make the changes in one of my include documents, delete the current folder in the htdocs of MAMP, save all the changes I made, copy the folder into htdocs, then start the servers and test the website.

Is there a more efficient way to test the look of a website that contains php through MAMP? Thanks!

---

**Clarification**

Sorry if the question is a little unclear, maybe it is just my ignorance towards MAMP's features.

So my question is: Is there a way to make changes to the code and run them on the website without having to change the contents of the htdocs folder? Maybe accessing and changing the files through the htdocs itself?

The htdocs folder is part of the MAMP application in which you put the contents of the website in order to test it.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP, but I suspect that the browser is the problem, did you try to delete the cache after making changes? And after deleting the cache press F5, not the back button in the browser.

Comment: If this helps any: I'm using safari on a mac. Should I look into try XAMPP instead of MAMP?

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you actually try to describe... Certainly one does not have to delete files or folders to get changes applied. So please try to add a few more details to your question describing your precise situation.

Comment: It's just a matter of preference, I said I'm using XAMPP to indicate I'm only guessing, and it doesn't take long to try if it solves the issue... sometimes CTRL+F5 is already enough.

Comment: Sorry if the question is a little unclear, maybe it is just my ignorance towards MAMP's features. So my question is: Is there a way to make changes to the code and run them on the website without having to change the contents of the htdocs folder. The htdocs folder is part of the MAMP application in which you put the contents of the website in order to test it.

Comment: I added your comment to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of php files you will have to open the pages via your mamp server, so don't just doubleclick a file or choose "open with ...[your broser], but (in the browser) use (for example) http://localhost/page1.php

`localhost` usually leads directly to that htdocs folder, so a path that in your filesystem is `htdocs/folder1/file1.php` can be addressed as `http://localhost/folder1/file1.php`

Refreshing that page in the browser will then show you all changes you made in the php files.

Comment: Awesome that worked. What I needed to do was put the website folder directly into the htdocs folder, then make all changes from there.